# Vue3 Router-Link rendering to specific Router-View

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

I have a VueJS version 3 view/page that will have two components within it. One of those components will have a contextual menu (Router-Links) where menu items will need to render to a specific Router-View. How do I tell Vue Router that I want the result of the Router-Link 'click' to render its resource into this specified Router-View?  I cannot find any mention of the target designation in the docs.

Comment: To specify which router-view to render the component to, you can use [named views](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#named-views). A named router-view will render the component with the corresponding name in the matched route record's components option.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Thank you! My answer was in Vue Router documentation. I misread it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the first reply from Keyboard Corporation. Op referred me to [Vue Router doc](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#named-views).